# how multiple values from a multi-select picklist represented in Apex

Tags: apex

In a single record, a user selects multiple values from a multi-select picklist.
How are the selected values represented in Apex?

Comment: Anzar, you know you could have simply created a multi-select picklist field in  your org, populated it, and then queried for it using the Developer Console to figure this out

Comment: Yep @cropredy. I tried that out and found the selected multiple values are separated by semicolons. "Value1;Value2:Value3"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A string with the selected values separated by a semicolon:

```
Account fruitVendor = [SELECT Fruits_Sold__c FROM Account WHERE Name = 'I Sell Fruits'];
System.debug(fruitVendor.Fruits_Sold__c);
```

> 15:11:33:027 USER_DEBUG [2]|DEBUG|Apple;Banana;Orange;Grape