# Multi-Select Picklist in Apex

Tags: apex, picklist, multi-select

I retrieved a multi-selected picklist values and I received the values separated by comma as below.

[image]

[image]

But I noticed another post with answer that selected multi values is separated by semicolon,
[how multiple values from a multi-select picklist represented in Apex](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/103559/how-multiple-values-from-a-multi-select-picklist-represented-in-apex/244294#244294)

Can anybody confirm which one is correct, comma or semicolon? Thanks...!

Comment: AFAIK it's ';' separated. If it's not a restricted picklist, not sure if there's any automation in your org to save them as ',' separated.

Answer (score 1):

By default in apex it will give you semicolon only. so split values by semicolon if you want in list.

Answer (score 1):

The values are separated by semi-colons, and no spaces. It is possible to have a value of "NE, SD", but that is only a **single** value, not two distinct values. Someone likely imported data with the incorrect format.